# Play an audio file when call is answered

Tags: java, android, audio

Hey how can I play/trigger an audio file when answering or ending a call, like whenever I click on the end call or receive call button, it should trigger a sound

It should be only played on the receiver's side, not on the caller's side.

Comment: Did you try BroadcastReceiver to listen for incoming and outgoing calls?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.